Iterate each cell with ExcelJS
I having trouble when I try to export an Excel with data al ready filled, this is the error message on console:
enter image description here
The total of results are 346880 with 28 headers that makes a total of 9,712,640 cells, and put so many console.log() too see better what's the real problema and end in this loop:
 headerRow.eachCell((cell, colNumber) => {
          cell.fill = { type: 'pattern', 
                        pattern: 'solid', 
                        fgColor: { argb: 'D9D9D9' } };
          cell.border = { top: { style: 'thin' }, 
                          left: { style: 'thin' }, 
                          bottom: { style: 'thin' }, 
                          right: { style: 'thin' } };
      
          const column = worksheet.getColumn(colNumber);
          const headerText = cell.text || '';
          const maxTextLength = Math.max(
            ...data.map(item => (item[colNumber - 1] || '').toString().length + headerText.length)
          );

          column.width = maxTextLength + 2;
        });

I try something like this:
const maxTextLengths [] = [];
for (let colNumber = 1; colNumber <= headerRow.cellCount; colNumber++) {
const headerText = headerRow.getCell(colNumber).text || '';
const maxLength = Math.max(
...data.map(item => (item[colNumber - 1] || '').toString().length + headerText.length)
);
maxTextLengths.push(maxLength);
}

headerRow.eachCell((cell, colNumber) => {
cell.fill = { type: 'pattern', pattern: 'solid', fgColor: { argb: 'D9D9D9' } };
cell.border = { top: { style: 'thin' }, left: { style: 'thin' }, bottom: { style: 'thin' }, right: { style: 'thin' } };

const column = worksheet.getColumn(colNumber);
column.width = maxTextLengths[colNumber - 1] + 2;
});

But got the same issue.

The problem is the call to Math.max(). It appears that you are looping through all 340,000+ rows which is causing the error. Instead of using Math.max(), get the longest cell length using something like:
let maxLength = 0
data.forEach(item => {
  const length = (item[colNumber - 1] || '').toString().length + headerText.length
  if (length > maxLength) {
    maxLength = length
  }
})



It barely works but it makes the entire system stop working. I gonna make and update, thank you btw.
